# Strategy for DLL production - VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, design-patterns

There is plenty of documentation out there that talks about design patterns (e.g. Visitor), SOLID (Single Responsibility etc), KISS (Keep it Simple, Stupid), tiered design etc.

One thing I don't fully understand is how to decide when a new project/DLL is required when extending an application.  Is there any criteria that is used?

For example, System.Windows.Forms (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.containercontrol.aspx) is part of System.Windows.Forms.dll yet it derives from System.MarshalByRefObject, which is part of mscorlib.dll.

Comment: Don't confuse layers and tiers.  Layering your code is almost always must.  But, only add tiers as necessary (KISS).

Comment: @Steven Doggart, are you saying that every DLL has layers?

Answer (score 4):

You're mixing up assemblies (DLLs) and namespaces.

[**Assemblies**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hk5f40ct.aspx) are the binary files which contain the implementations of classes, etc.

[**Namespaces**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z2kcy19k.aspx) are just a way to organize classes, enums, etc. into logical groups, to prevent from having every class accessible from every level, and prevent naming conflicts (eg. `System.Windows.Forms.Timer` and `System.Threading.Timer`).

`System.Windows.Forms` doesn't *derive* from `System`, and `System` doesn't live solely in mscorlib.dll.  Anyone can put anything in the `System` namespace - even you could do it.  It's just a sub-namespace of `System`.

There are several reasons for breaking a subset of code out into a separate assembly. A big one is re-usability. If you have some common controls or utilities, you can maintain it in its own DLL and use it across projects without copy-and-pasting of code.

Comment: Thanks for correcting me, I meant to put: System.MarshalByRefObject.  I have updated the question.

Comment: I guess I don't understand what your *actual* question is, then.

Comment: No, this is a good answer.  Can you explain what you mean by: System doesn't live solely in mscorlib.dll

Comment: I don't have an example, but I am fairly confident that there are other classes that live in the `System` namespace, which are implemented in assemblies other than mscorlib.dll. Look in System.dll

Comment: Can you give any other benefits of creating a new DLL except reuseability? or point me to a link.  +1 by the way.

Comment: I'm finishing up a project now that used pluggable modules. Interface-implementing classes were dynamically loaded from separate module assemblies in a "modules" directory. Code that was shared between these modules was implemented in a separate "Utils" assembly that each one references.

Answer (score 1):

Don't confuse tiers with layers.  Layering your code is almost always a must.  Splitting your code out into separate physical tiers, however, is something that you usually don't want to do until you actually need to (following the KISS principle).

If you layer your code properly, then when the time comes that you need to break it out into separate tiers, doing so should be a very painless process.  If, however, you never layered your code properly you'll find that splitting out the tiers will be very difficult.

As a simple example, lets say you create a login form and lets say you put all the logic to gather the system information, access the database, validate the user credentials, and build the permissions, all directly into the WinForm class.  The code I just described has only 1 layer and it has only 1 tier.  If you then found yourself needing to create a web-based login page using ASP.NET, you would find it very difficult to reuse that existing code.  With the web based login, you'd want to at the very least, separate the UI logic from the business/data access logic, but because it's all directly in the WinForm class, it's all unusable without re-factoring the code.

Now, let's say, instead of putting all that code in the form, you took the time to layer it properly.  Let's say you broke out all of the code that accessed the database about put it all into data access classes.  And then you put all of the business logic code put it all in business classes.  At that point, the actual code in the WinForm class should be limited to doing nothing but UI related logic such as handling control events, setting labels, etc.  In this second example. you still only have 1 tier, but you have three distinct and independent layers (viz. UI, Business, Data Access).

If you had already layered your code like that, then when the time came that you needed to reuse it in the web-based project, you could easily move the business and data access layers into a class library (dll) and then reuse them in the ASP.NET project for the server-side tier.

Breaking your code into separate class libraries is only typically necessary in two situations:

1. You need to reuse the code in multiple projects
2. You need to divide your project into multiple tiers

Even if you put all your code in a single project, as long as it is well-layered, it will be very easy to split the project up into multiple class libraries when such a situation arises.  So the big design issue is not how many DLL's you have.  Rather, the big design issue is how many layers you have.  Once you have the code layered, it will be easy to move it around between different projects as necessary.

In practical terms, even when you don't need to reuse the code between projects nor support n-tiers, you may still legitimately choose to divide your layers into separate class libraries.  It may make sense to do so purely for organizational purposes, or for consistency.  For instance, if another developer comes behind you and sees classes in a class library called "MyCompany.Feature.Business", they can safely assume that those classes are all part of the business logic layer.  In that way, breaking your code up into separate class libraries can be self-documenting.

There are other reasons too, for putting code in dlls.  For instance, it makes it easy to support plug-in architectures or to make it easier to update one part of the application at a time.